# Symfony2 "Object of class could not be converted to int"

Tags: symfony

So i have a script that works well for my creation. It populates a select box with geckos that match the current user's id. Works great, however, when i go to edit an entry in the database i get the following error:

> Notice: Object of class Proxies__CG__\Breedr\GeckoBundle\Entity\Gecko
>   could not be converted to int

The code for my `createCreateForm` is this (this is the bit that works fine):

```
private function createCreateForm(Weight $entity)
    {   
        $currentUserId = $this->getUser()->getId();
        $sql = 'select id, name from gecko where user_id = ?';        
        $stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->execute(array($currentUserId)); 
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $form = $this->createForm(new WeightType($results), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('weight_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        // dump($results);
        // exit();
        return $form;
    }
```

And after i got other errors, i thought that copying to my `createEditForm` would fix my issue:

```
private function createEditForm(Weight $entity)
{
    $currentUserId = $this->getUser()->getId();
    $sql = 'select id, name from gecko where user_id = ?';        
    $stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute(array($currentUserId)); 
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $form = $this->createForm(new WeightType($results), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('weight_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
```

But it didn't and now i get the error i quoted above. Below is my `WeightType` form so you can see how it's working:

```
<?php

namespace Breedr\GeckoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class WeightType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $geckosList;

    /**
     * param array $geckosList It can be passed from controller 
     * when creating form instance
     */
    public function __construct($geckosList)
    {
        $this->geckosList = $geckosList;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $geckosChoice = array();

        foreach ($this->geckosList as $entry) {
            $geckosChoice[ $entry['id'] ] = $entry['name'];
        }

        $builder
            ->add('weighedDate')
            ->add('weight')
            ->add('geckoId', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $geckosChoice  
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Breedr\GeckoBundle\Entity\Weight'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'breedr_geckobundle_weight';
    }
}
```

This is for my `editAction`:

```
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Weight')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Weight entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

So my question is, how can i overcome this error and show the current gecko's value in the drop down (the point is that if they chose the wrong gecko they could easily change the name, but my logic behind this hasn't worked at all!)

Any help is welcomed, and i thank you in advance to any that can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest to use Doctrine query builder inside the form, and also the `entity` form field. You code can be something like this:

**Controller**

```
private function createEditForm(Weight $entity)
{
    $currentUser = $this->getUser();

    $form = $this->createForm(new WeightType($currentUser), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('weight_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
```

**Form**

```
    /**
     * @var User
     */
    protected $currentUser;

    /**
     * param User $currentUser
     */
    public function __construct(User $currentUser)
    {
        $this->currentUser = $currentUser;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $currentUser = $this->currentUser;

        $builder
            ->add('weighedDate')
            ->add('weight')
        ;
        $builder->add('gecko', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Breedr\GeckoBundle\Entity\Gecko',
            'property' => 'name',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($currentUser) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('g')
                        ->where('g.user = :currentUser')
                        ->orderBy('g.name ASC')
                        ->setParameter('currentUser', $currentUser);
                },
        ));
    }
```

The [doc's](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) reference.

Comment: I have already built a query for my create action, that's what i have shown in the question. It works for create, but i can't get it to work for the edit action

Comment: I've added in my current WeightType form so you can see i have already attempted this

Comment: @AndyHolmes Why are you using `choice` field instead of `entity`? And if so, why do not to consider the [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) usage? Doctrine says that related entity couldn't be converted to integer.

Comment: I was using choice as i thought that was right for what i was doing. As i say it works perfectly for the create action/form but i just can't get it working for the edit. If i alter my current code i get "Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'". The reason i ask on here is because i find asking actual people a bit more helpful than reading the docs over and over haha

Comment: "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Breedr\GeckoBundle\Form\WeightType::__construct() must be an instance of Breedr\GeckoBundle\Form\User, integer given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/breedr/src/Breedr/GeckoBundle/Controller/WeightController.php on line 173 and defined" for example

Comment: @AndyHolmes Did you simply "copypaste" it without adding appropriate `use` statements?) Please consider my code just as an example.

Comment: Yes sorry, i realise this now haha. I am using your code as an example and am working toward a working example. Thank you :)